# Name of fabric insulator found inside motors

Tags: motor, identification, thermal, insulation

What is the name of the fabric sleeve insulator used for components (typically fuses) and solder joints found inside motor windings?

Can regular heat shrink tubing be used as a substitute?

[image]
*Image by cwbenz. Retrieved from [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/FAN-repair/).*

Comment: maybe fiberglass and resin

Comment: Heatshrink may degrade at lower temperatures than that stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called sleeving. In this case it looks like uncoated [NOMEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomex), but the specific brand might vary.
This is applied in electromotors and generators where this fiberglass-like sleeving is impregnated with insulating lacquer or resin during dip-sealing or vacuum impregnation.

This material is used because it can handle high temperatures and is not flammable. It also has a much higher kV/mm than regular heat shrink.

In fact, heat-shrink degrades rather quickly, and can becomes actually conductive, and is typically avoided when long term insulation is required. 
Hence why heat-shrink is more a low voltage repair material.

If you are not going to use lacquer or impregnation I suggest you look for coated fiberglass sleeve. This is coated with polyurethane or acrylic.
A brand name of this could be Vidaflex.